# Is this epsilon delta argument that $\lim_{n \to\infty} (0.3)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ valid?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I'd like to know if this proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (0.3)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ is valid. My approach seems too easy.

For $\epsilon >0$, I need to find an $n_0$ such that whenever $n>n_0$, we have  $\lvert (0.3)^\frac {1}{n}-1\lvert<\epsilon$. 
So trying to simplify, I got $$-1<(0,3)^\frac {1}{n}<\epsilon+1$$
Therefore, $$(0.3)<(\epsilon+1)^{n}$$ 
$$(0.3)<1+n\epsilon \leq (1+\epsilon)^{n}$$ 
Since epsilon is greater than $0$ we know that $(0.3)<1+n\epsilon$ is true for all $n>0$. Therefore, given $\epsilon >0$, let $n_0>0$ and choose $n>n_0$.

Edit: I used Bernoulli's inequality to introduce this result $1+n\epsilon \leq (1+\epsilon)^{n}$

Comment: How do you deduce the last line from the penultimate line? You go from $a < c$... to.... $a < b \leq c$... you slipped in $1+n\epsilon$ between the two other quantities.

Comment: I used Bernoulli's Inequality to deduce that $1+n\epsilon \leq (1+\epsilon)^{n}$

Comment: Your "trying to simplify" is incorrect. What you need to show is more like $1 - 0.3^{\frac1n} < \epsilon$, or $0.3^{\frac1n} > 1-\epsilon$.

Comment: How'd you get the *first* line.  $|0.3^n - 1| < \epsilon \implies 1-\epsilon < 0.3^n < 1 + \epsilon$.  It's not enough that $0.3^n < 1 + \epsilon$ you must have $1 - \epsilon < 0. 3^n$ as well.  we can assume $0 < 1 - \epsilon$ and so $(1-\epsilon)^n < 0.3 < (1+\epsilon)^n$.  So... you aren't done.

Comment: A red flag should have been $n_0=1; n = 2$.  Clearly $|0.3^{\frac 12} - 1|= |\sqrt{.3} - 1| =  < \epsilon$ is not true for all $\epsilon$. (That'd only be true for constants.  The $n$ *must* be dependent upon the $\epsilon$ else you'd have a constant limit that always work.  That can only happen with an equality.  And $0.3^{\frac 1n} \ne 1$ for all $n > n_0$ ever.)

Comment: @fleablood the exponent is $1/n$ and not $n$.

Comment: @E.Nole yes but suppose the first inequality says 4 < 5. Then you say well this new expression $(1+n\epsilon)$ is less than 5. OK good. But how do you know $4 < (1+n\epsilon)$? What if $(1+n\epsilon) = 3$?

Comment: Yeah, I made a typo.  Doesn't change anything.  Deducing that $0.3^{\frac 1n} < 1 < 1 + \epsilon$ ore equivalently then $0.3 < 1 < 1 + n\epsilon < (1 + \epsilon)^n$ is all very true.  But that is only *half* (the easy half) of the problem.  You must also show that $1- \epsilon < e^{\frac 1n}$ and that requires a lot more work. and is not at trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler argument,
not original with me,
that works for any
$0 < a < 1$.
Your case is
$a = .3$.

Since $0 < a < 1$,
there is a $b > 0$
such that
$a = \frac1{1+b}$.
Explicitly,
$b = \frac1{a}-1$.

Then,
by Bernoulli,
$(1+b)^n
\ge 1+bn
\gt bn
=n(\frac1{a}-1)
$
so
$a^n
=\dfrac1{(1+b)^n}
\lt \dfrac1{n(\frac1{a}-1)}
= \dfrac{a}{n(1-a)}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that  $$|(0.3)^{1/n}−1|<ϵ \iff  1-\epsilon <(0.3)^{1/n} <1+ϵ $$

Apparently you have missed some parts in this inequality which made your argument questionable.